# Не переключаются потоки в java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Писал программу по уроку проверил каждую запятую,не знаю в чём дело.

```
class Thread2 implements Runnable {
String str;
Thread2 (String str) {
this.str = str;

}
public void run () {

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
System.out.print (str);
}
public static void main (String args) {
  new Thread (new Thread2 ("One")).start ();
  new Thread (new Thread2 ("Two")).start ();
}
}
```

С начало выводится 30 раз One а потом 30 Two. Почему подпроцессы не переключаются?

Answer (score 5):

Почему не чередуются One и Two? Вероятно, первый поток успевает отработать до запуска второго. Добавьте Thread.sleep(1) внутрь цикла в методе run().

Comment: хм... а в видео уроке они чередуются!Дело в версии java или процессоре?

Comment: Ты в релизной конфигурации без отладчика запускал?

Comment: эмм.. просто запустил в эклипсе

Comment: эмм.. просто запустил в эклипсе

Это и есть с отладчиком.

Comment: И что это меняет?

Comment: @Vikkingg, разница в скорости. Все это легко гуглится.

Answer (score 2):

Слишком быстро выводится - поставьте 1000 или больше, тогда увидите

Comment: не ,ну ребята я делал всё как в видео уроке.Тока там в консоли компилировали,а я в эклипсе!

Comment: Как в видео уроке у вас не получится. Вытесняющая многозадачность никак не регламентирует порядок выполнения разных потоков без применения средств синхронизации. Вам верно подсказывают, что увеличение кол-ва выводов с 30 до большего значения может помочь (в том смысле что в выводе будут присутсвовать значения из двух потоков). Но совершенно непонятно, чего вы ожидаете и хотите этим добиться.